# bug in form. Help me please

Tags: html

I found bug in tag form. From this code:

```
<form>
<input type="text">
</form>
```

I type something in textbox and enter, Form is submit. But I rewrite code to this

```
<form>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
</form>
```

I type something in textbox and enter again, Form isn't submit.

I have never met before. What happen? Someone can tell me.
Thank you for help or suggestion.

Comment: You did not close the `<input>`-element, maybe your browser got confused?

Comment: Please post the contents of the _entire_ form (as it is).

Answer (score 2):

you have to specify that a input submits the form

```
<input type="submit" type="text">
```

you might also want to define what happens when there is a submission
for example :

```
<form action="cgi-bin/formmail.pl" method="post">
```

Comment: Are you sure it is: `<input type="submit" type="text">`? Why there is 2 `**type**` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
<input id="submit-button" type="submit" tabindex="110" value="Post Your Answer">
```

(look at the source of this page)

and specify some action in form field.

Answer (score 0):

Name your inputs, or provide an id. How does the browser know how to post your data? It doesn't, so it cannot make an auto-submit on enter.